# Disable "manage plugin" from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to disable "manage plugin" option itself from jenkins.
Does anyone have any clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way you can only disable the manage plugin option. However, you can disable the entire "Manage Jenkins" option, which will also restrict access to the plugins area.

To do this, go to: `<jenkins-url>/manage/configureSecurity/`, select "Matrix-based security" from the authorization dropdown, and select your preferences. For example:

[image]

The above matrix will allow authenticated users to do anything except go into the "Manage Jenkins" section.